# Does Doctrine use MySQL indexes?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Will Doctrine use indexes that are defined in the MySQL server but was never defined in the code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you have to explicitly define that in your code otherwise your code is not completely synchronized with the DB. You ca use something like this: `code` @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="name_idx", columns={"name"})}) `code`. Just replace the name of the index with the index name in your current DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "use indexes" you mean use them for optimal querying then answer is yes. From database's perspective Doctrine merely prepares query and receives data, it's up to MySQL to decide how the query will be performed. Downside of not having those indexes defined in Doctrine is that when using schema creation or migration tools Doctrine will try to remove them as according to Doctrine's knowledge, they shouldn't exist.